# How to add a package to all Debian distros?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, debian

How to add a package to all Debian distros?

If the package would be accepted by the community, anyone who does `sudo apt-get install example` could install it from any Debian distro (whether Debian, Ubuntu, or anything else).

How is this possible, if at all?

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMaintainer and https://wiki.debian.org/DebianDeveloper

Comment: Start at http://mentors.debian.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you get your package into Debian itself, it will eventually make its way into all the derivatives. To do so, look at [Debian mentors](https://mentors.debian.net/) and read the documentation there — in particular the [introduction for maintainers](https://mentors.debian.net/intro-maintainers) (and all the linked documentation).

You’ll find help on the related [mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-mentors/) and IRC channel (`#debian-mentors` on OFTC).